# Send radio selection to function along with textbox

Tags: php, arrays

I've got some code working that takes the text from my input box and moves it across to a function. I'm now trying to change it so I add another form element, a radio button and I want to access the choice within my functions.php file.

This is my current code which works for the post name, but what if I want to also grab the colours boxes that was selected too?

main.php

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $data = $_POST['name']; // the data from the form input.
}

?>

 ...
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Acme Corp"/>
    <input name="colour" type="radio" value="red">Red<br>
    <input name="colour" type="radio" value="blue">Blue<br>
    <input name="colour" type="radio" value="green">Green<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <img src="pngfile.php?data=<?php print urlencode($data);?>"
          alt="png php file">
```

I guess I confused because currently it is calling this:

pngfile.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'functions.php';  
     $inputData = urldecode($_GET['data']);
   process($inputData);
   exit;
?>
```

Which calls functions.php

```
<?php
function process($inputdata)
{
...
```

EDIT: What I have tried:

main.php [Change]

```
 $data = $_POST['name'] && $_POST['colour']
```

But I'm not really sure how to progress.

Comment: Why you using $_GET for colour ...It should be $_POST['colour'] as you form method is POST...

Comment: Oh yes, a typo sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Never trust user input***. Sanitize and validate your inputs before using them.
This can be arranged better, but the basics are still true.

PHP Manual: [filter_input_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php)

PHP Manual: [filter_var_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php)

### Small Function Library

```
function sanitizeArray($filterRules)
{
   return filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filterRules, true)
}

function validateArray($filteredData, $validationRules)
{
   return filter_var_array($filteredData, $validationRules, true);
}

function checkFilterResults(array $testArray, array &$errors)
{
   if (!in_array(false, $testArray, true) || !in_array(null, $testArray, true)) {
       foreach($testArray as $key => $value)
       {
           $errors[$key] = '';
       }

       return true;
   }

   if ($testArray['name'] !== true) { //You can make a function and do various test.
       $errors['name'] = 'That is not a valid name.'; 
   }

   if ($testArray['clour'] !== true) { //You can make a function and do many test.
       $errors['colour'] = 'That is not a valid colour.'; 
   }

   return false;
}

function processUserInput(array &$filteredData, array $filterRulesArray, array $validationRulesArray, array &$cleanData, array &$errors)
{
    $filteredInput = null;
    $tempData = sanitizeArray($filterRulesArray);

    if (!$checkFilterResults($tempData, $errors)){
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("An input value was unable to be sanitized.");
        //Consider forcing the page to redraw.
    }

    $filteredData = $tempData;
    $validatedData = validateArray($filteredData, $validationRulesArray);

    if (!$checkFilterResults($validatedData, $errors)){
        return false;
    }

    $errors['form'] = ''; 
    $cleanData = $validatedData;
    return true;
}

function htmlEscapeArray(array &$filteredData)
{
    foreach($filteredData as $key => &$value)
    {
        $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8', false);
    }

    return; 
}
```

---

### Basic Main Line

```
try {
        $filterRulesArray = [];      //You define this.
        $filteredData     = [];    //A temporary array.

        $validationRulesArray = [];   //You define this.
        $validatedData        = null; //Another temporary array.

        $results   = null;     //Input processing results: true or false.
        $cleanData = null;     //Filtered and validated input array.
        $errors    = [];       //Any errors that have accumulated.

        if (isset($_POST, $_POST['submit'], $_POST['colour']) && !empty($_POST)) {
            $results = processUserInput($filteredData, $filterRulesArray, $validationRulesArray, $cleanData, $errors);
        } else {
            $errors['form'] = "You must fill out the form."
        }

        if ($results === true) {
            $name   = $cleanData['name'];   //You can do what you want.
            $colour = $cleanData['colour']; //You can do what you want.
            //header("Location: http://url.com/registration/thankYou/")
            //exit;
        }

        //Prepare user input for re-display in browser
        htmlEscapeArray($filteredData);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header("Location: http://url.com/samePage/"); //Force a page reload.
}
```

---

Let the form redraw if input processing fails. 
Use the `$errors` array to display error messages.
Use the `$filteredData` array to make the form sticky.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your Webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Form</h1>
        <form action="/" method="post">

            <!-- Make spots for error messages -->

            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Acme Corp" value="PUT PHP HERE"/>

            <!-- No time to display sticky radios! :-) -->
            <input name="colour" type="radio" checked="checked" value="red">Red<br>
            <input name="colour" type="radio" value="blue">Blue<br>
            <input name="colour" type="radio" value="green">Green<br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Tip:

It may be better to submit numbers for radios, as opposed to longer string values like (red, green, blue). Numbers are easier to *sanitize* and *validate*. Naturally, then you must *translate* the input number into its corresponding string. You would do that ***after validation*** has finished, but ***before using*** the values. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the code. I do appreciate you showing me how I can santintize my data but I'm still a bit confused about how to be bringing across not only the text input but also the radio selection to my function

Comment: @Jimmy, this should sort you out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extremely detailed answer, that has helped me a lot

Comment: You are welcome. Try to break a task into parts / functions. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can access this using array like this.

```
$data[] = $_POST['name'];
  $data[] =$_POST['colour'];
```

Or combine both variable

```
$data = $_POST['name'].'&'.$_POST['colour'];
```

Comment: `$dat = $_POST['name'].'&'.$_POST['colour'];`

Comment: Never combine un-sanitized and un-validated data.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array in php for this process as follows:

```html
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $array_val = array(
        "name"=> $_POST['name'],
        "color"=> $_POST['color']
    );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How then do I get this to my function, is the right way to do something like this? ```$inputData = urldecode($_GET['name']); $colorData = urldecode($_GET['color']);
   process($inputData, $colorData);```

Comment: The wrong array elements are being used. All required elements should be checked for their presence as input. You don't know if `colour` is there, but you are attempting to access it.